# sum of two objects and show the result in json format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects.

Scenario: I want a function that sums up two different objects which is stored in the local file, and returns an object in the same style as other two objects.

First JSON

```
{
"data": [{
  "x": "Q1 (J, F, M)",
  "y": [100, 500, 0],
  "tooltip": "this is tooltip"
}, {
  "x": "Q2(A, M, J)",
  "y": [300, 100, 100]
}, {
  "x": "Q3(J, A, S)",
  "y": [351,200,700]
}, {
  "x": "Q4 (Q, N, D)",
  "y": [54, 0, 879]
}]
}
```

Second JSON

```
{
"data": [{
  "x": "Q1 (J, F, M)",
  "y": [100, 500, 200],
  "tooltip": "this is tooltip"
}, {
  "x": "Q2(A, M, J)",
  "y": [300, 100, 100]
}, {
  "x": "Q3(J, A, S)",
  "y": [351,400,555]
}, {
  "x": "Q4 (Q, N, D)",
  "y": [54, 30, 879]
}]
}
```

result will be sum of both objects

```
{
"data": [{
  "x": "Q1 (J, F, M)",
  "y": [200, 1000, 200],
  "tooltip": "this is tooltip"
}, {
  "x": "Q2(A, M, J)",
  "y": [600, 200, 200]
}, {
  "x": "Q3(J, A, S)",
  "y": [702,600,1255]
}, {
  "x": "Q4 (Q, N, D)",
  "y": [108, 30, 1758]
}]
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: yeah... sum them.

Comment: Are both source arrays guaranteed to have the same number of elements (4)?

Comment: Use the `+` operator

Comment: JSON is a string format. You just have objects here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your arrays have always the same number of elements (4 in the example, 1 for each quarter), then you could use this ES6 function:

```js
function addObjects(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj1.data.map( (o1, i) => Object.assign({}, o1,  
        { y: o1.y.map( (n1, j) => n1 + obj2.data[i].y[j] ) }
    ));
}

// Sample data
var obj1 = {
    "data": [{
      "x": "Q1 (J, F, M)",
      "y": [100, 500, 0],
      "tooltip": "this is tooltip"
    }, {
      "x": "Q2(A, M, J)",
      "y": [300, 100, 100]
    }, {
      "x": "Q3(J, A, S)",
      "y": [351,200,700]
    }, {
      "x": "Q4 (Q, N, D)",
      "y": [54, 0, 879]
    }]
};

var obj2 = {
    "data": [{
      "x": "Q1 (J, F, M)",
      "y": [100, 500, 200],
      "tooltip": "this is tooltip"
    }, {
      "x": "Q2(A, M, J)",
      "y": [300, 100, 100]
    }, {
      "x": "Q3(J, A, S)",
      "y": [351,400,555]
    }, {
      "x": "Q4 (Q, N, D)",
      "y": [54, 30, 879]
    }]
};

console.log(addObjects(obj1, obj2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It help a lot

Comment: hi, I need on more help to save this data to my local file automatically without showing any file download link. From morning i am searching it in google but didn't found anything. @trincot

Comment: That is not possible. JavaScript running in a browser is on purpose not allowed to do this, as this would pose a security issue. You could however save it to [`localStorage`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/428/web-storage#t=201703291738429135515), which works with approximately the same principles as cookies, but allows larger sized data.

Comment: actually given data I want to show in graph format. And for the graph, i am using Angular-charts.
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EHgL6HeMxaKfJ7kKpUZf?p=preview) 
But the graph is not showing. @trincot can you please guide me why it is not working

Comment: You are using `$.ajax` in the wrong way, but really you should ask this as a new question, as it has little to do with the question on this page. I'll be happy to answer if you post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139405/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-trincot).